# How to align a single md-tab element to the right

Tags: css, angularjs, tabs, angular-material

Is it possible to align a single `md-tab` element to the right of `md-tabs`, while having the rest of the tabs remain where they are?

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 |                                      | Select |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I don't necessarily need the select element in a tab, but if I put the `select` outside of the `md-tabs` it shows up under the tabs, which isn't what I want.

I know it looks like a simple question, but I've been struggling to make this work for a while now.

**Here's the code:**

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYmjVB?editors=1011)

Comment: Have you tried float:right?

Comment: try with md-toolbar

Comment: I've tried float:right, wrapping the tab in a div, etc.. nothing seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use absolute positioning for `select` inside parent container, but this is a dirty solution: select can overlap the tabs in case of many tabs in a row or a small screen width.

Please check this fiddle, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lxscboy/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<md-tab label="three">
<md-content class="md-padding">
<h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
<p>3</p>
</md-content>
</md-tab>
<mat-tab disabled></mat-tab>  --adds spaces
<mat-tab disabled></mat-tab>
<mat-tab disabled></mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="select"></mat-tab>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: In order to align select tab to the right side,before select label add mat tabs with disabled attribute,it will move the mat tab to the right side.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using **flex** ?

Then try this.

```
<div ng-cloak>
<md-content>
    <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom>
        <md-tab label="one">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab One</h1>
                <p>1</p>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="two">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Two</h1>
                <p>2</p>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <md-tab label="three">
            <md-content class="md-padding">
                <h1 class="md-display-2">Tab Three</h1>
                <p>3</p>
            </md-content>
        </md-tab>
        <span flex></span>
        <select>
            <option value="">asdasd</option>
        </select>
    </md-tabs>
</md-content>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the select element doesn't display at all